# unable to add a paintComponent panel to a frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, paintcomponent

I'm having problems adding a JPanel, which has a paintComponent in it, to a JFrame.
If this is the only thing I add to the frame, it works.  But as soon as I add a layout manager and add other components to the JFrame, it no longer shows the panel with the painting!

To make this clearer ...

This is the code that works and the JPanel is successfully shown:

The panel that draws the sign (in reality i am not trying to paint hello, this is to simply the code here)

```
public class SignPanel2 extends JPanel {
public int hello;

public void paintComponent(Graphics comp) {
    Graphics g = (Graphics) comp;
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(70, 250, 150, 150);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK); 

    if (hello > 0) 
        g.drawString("h",135, 270);

    if (hello > 1 ) 
        g.drawString("h e",135, 270);

    if (hello > 2) 
        g.drawString("h e l",135, 270);

    if (hello > 3) 
        g.drawString("h e l l",135, 270);

    if (hello > 4) 
        g.drawString("h e l l o",135, 270);
}

}
```

The frame i put the panel on:

```
public class SignFrame extends JFrame {

// the constructor method
public SignFrame () {

    super("This is the title of the Sign Frame");
    setSize(300,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // make a container for the frame
    Container content = getContentPane();

    // call from the drawing panel
    SignPanel2 signpanel = new SignPanel2();
    // change class variable of SignPanel
    signpanel.hello = 5;
    signpanel.repaint();


    // add signpanel to container
    content.add(signpanel);

    setContentPane(content);

    setVisible(true);

}

}
```

The main class

```
public class TheSignMain {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    SignFrame signframe = new SignFrame();

}

}
```

The above works perfectly fine and gives me a frame with the desired drawing in it.

But if I add other components to the frame and add a layout manager, it no longer shows me the painting.  even if I use repaint().
I have to include a layout manager, otherwise it adds the panel with the painting, but not the other components.
This is how my frame class looks now, and this is where i'm having problems.

public class SignFrame extends JFrame {

```
// the constructor method
public SignFrame () {

    super("This is the title of the Sign Frame");
    setSize(300,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // make a container for the frame
    Container content = getContentPane();


    // need a layout manager to decide the arrangement of the components on the container
    FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
    // designate the layout manager to the container
    content.setLayout(flo);


    // make components
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    JButton play = new JButton("Play");
    JButton pause = new JButton("Pause");
    JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
    // add components to a panel
    buttons.add(play);
    buttons.add(pause);
    buttons.add(stop);
    // add panel to frame container
    content.add(buttons);


    // call from the drawing panel
    SignPanel2 signpanel = new SignPanel2();
    // change class variable of SignPanel
    signpanel.hello = 5;
    signpanel.repaint();


    // add signpanel to container
    content.add(signpanel);

    setContentPane(content);

    setVisible(true);

}

}
```

I am totally new to Java, so any help will be much appreciated.
Sorry for all that code and thanks for your help!!

Comment: +1, though, nice question. Helped me learn something today :-)

Comment: @Gagandeep ... I'm not sure what I've done to your answer.  I clicked on the tick icon next to JB Nizet's to make it the accepted answer (i.e. it solved the question), but then your reply vanished.  I didn't think it would delete any other replies.  I do apologise, I only registered today, so I am new to the way the forum works.

Comment: Nah that was deliberate, I deleted that myself. Since what you wanted and what JB Nizet told you on that is so good. Just Keep Smiling, nothing to worry about :-)

Comment: Are you facing any problems with the same ? Something not dealt with last time, please do specify ?

Answer (score 4):

Not tested, but the flow layout probably uses the preferred size of your panel, and you probably haven't overridden `getPreferredSize()` to return something other than a [0, 0] dimension.

Also, you should encapsulate the change of the hello variable in a `setHello()` method that calls `repaint()`. The calling code shouldn't have to deal with repaint. The panl should know when it has to be repainted, and call repaint itself.

Comment: Hi thanks for the super fast reply.  much appreciated.  I am really very new to coding.  I just started learning and writing a week ago.

Where exactly do I put the getPrefferedSize() line?  In the class with the frame?
signpanel.getPrefferedSize(150,150);

Comment: Actually just tried coding that and it says 'The method getPrefferedSize() is undefined for the type SignPanel2'
..

Comment: The method is named getPreferredSize() and takes no argument. You must implement it in your custom panel (SignPanel2), and it must override JComponent's getPreferredSize() method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize%28%29

Comment: Oops ... my spelling error spotted :s
getPreferredSize()

so where do I add this ...?

Comment: This is what I added ...

signpanel.getPrefferedSize();

Comment: This is what I added ...
SignPanel2 signpanel = new SignPanel2();
signpanel.getPrefferedSize();
content.add(signpanel);
this still doesnt add the panel with the component.  for now I have removed signpanel.hello=5, and just set hello  to 5 in the jpanel.  just to see if the painting is coming up at all.

Comment: @phy2sma : By what JB Nizet has written he means, that your class SignPanel2 must have the definition of the method getPreferredSize(), just like you had override your paintComponent() method, inside the same class. Just make that method return something like return new Dimension(300, 500);

Comment: Just noticed your reply to my comments.  Ok I am now trying to put it in my SignPanel2 class.  but do i just write getPreferredSize();  do I not need to write (something).getPrefferedSize();  And do I add it into the paintComponent method?  Its still not solving the problem

Comment: @phy2sma: if you don't know what overriding means, then you don't know what inheritance is all about. Read the Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html. Yous SignPanel2 class must have another method called `getPreferredSize()` which returns a `Dimension` object.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that.  I now have the getPreferredSize() method in my SignPanel and it draws what in the paintComponent.  
Now I am trying to work on the method of the hello variable.

Comment: Ok, added two methods in the SignPanel2 class.  One for getPrefferedSize and one for setHello.  Now from the SignFrame class I can setHello and it will repaint the desired graphics.  
Thanks for your help!

Comment: This was only a short version of the main program I am writing, which is actually to make a game which displays different versions of the drawing on the paintComponent.  I'm now going to incorporate what I've learnt into that, and hopefully it should work.  If I have any more queries, I may be back

Comment: my actual program has a GridLayout, and the panel doesnt show up.  I changed the layout manager of this program too and the panel vanishes from this too ...